# Help with a regex expression

Tags: c#, regex, capture-group

I am trying to get the word after `Sysdba.` out of a string. Here is a example where my result would be `PRODUCTION`

```
CAST(CASE WHEN SYSDBA.PRODUCTION.SHIPPING_COMPLETE_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [Shiping Completed]]
```

I created the regex expression

```
Regex CatagoryRegex = new Regex(@"SYSDBA\.(.#)\.", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

however when I call `var tmp = CatagoryRegex.Match(SelectText);` I get no matches. I know I am most likely making a simple mistake but I can not spot it.

Comment: I don't see "PREPRODUCTION" anywhere in your string to parse. Did you mean just "PRODUCTION"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specific problem is that `.#` will match "any character", followed by `#` character.

The simplest fix might be to use `.+` but this is a bit crude for what you appear to be doing. A step better is the non-greedy `.+?` which will only capture upto the next `.` (unless it has to go further), but I would probably go a step further than this even...

To prevent `.` inside the captured group, try this expression:

```
"SYSDBA\.([^.]+)\."
```

Where `[^.]` is any character not a `.` (no need to escape in character classes), and the `+` means "one or more".

If you want to potentially allow `.` inside your captured group, you could use:

```
"SYSDBA\.(\S+)\."
```

Where the `\S` is any non-whitespace character (so stops matching if spaces or newlines).

Comment: I withdrew my answer. I think this is the best answer so far. +1

Comment: I thouht # was the non greedy version of * insted of +? that was my stupid mistake.

Comment: Thanks Pretzel. I almost did go the `\w` route, but I don't know enough about what might be accepted/required to match (e.g. if this is TSQL then `[` and `]` might be involved). Anyway, I've updated a bit further - it's still not as complete/thorough as it could be, but I have to go now - if anyone thinks of any more to add feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Scott, I've never seen that, though I don't use .NET regex so it's possible. However, the only 'special use' for `#` I'm aware of with any regex is for comments - e.g. `(?x)#endofline` or `(?#inline)`.

Comment: Yes, `\S` will match the exact opposite of `\s`, and `\s` is effectively `[ \t\n\r]` (and maybe other whitespace chars). If you want to exclude underscores, you can use either `(?!_)\S` or `[^\s_]` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean `.*` instead of `.#`.

Comment: .* would be too greedy and gobble up everything... well, everything up to the next escaped period.